# Simplify a active menu jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to simplify this code:

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll scroll mousewheel keydown', function () {
    if ($('#home-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
    } else if ($('#what-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        $('.li-width:first-child > li > .li-underline').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('#case-studies-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        $('.li-width:nth-child(2) > li > .li-underline').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('#team-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        $('.li-width:nth-child(3) > li > .li-underline').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('#clients-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        $('.li-width:nth-child(4) > li > .li-underline').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('#contact-section').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        $('.li-width:nth-child(5) > li > .li-underline').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

As am I am basicaly repeating the same function over and over.

something like this would work?:

```
var activeSection = $('#what-section', 'team-section');

$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll scroll mousewheel keydown', function () {
        activeSection.hasClass('cd-section visible') {
           $('.li-underline').removeClass('active');
        }
```

Comment: Adding HTML and CSS will help. Creating Live/JsFiddle Demo will be easier to play with code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to those elements and select them by that, so:

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll scroll mousewheel keydown', function () {
    if ($('.newclass').hasClass('cd-section visible')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
```

}

You can add multiple class to a tag like:

```
<div class="one two three"></div>
```

And select them like:

```
$('.two, .three').css('background',''yellow');
```